# Multiple instances of component causing issues when referencing DOM elements - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a header that reveals a shape while scrolling down the page. This worked exactly as planned however when using multiple instances of the same component (for multiple headers) all instances take on the values of the first instance.

Presumably this is because I am using `GetElementById()` and with multiple instances there are now multiple `div`s with the same ID. The way I am binding the style may also be causing similar issues.

How can I get each script to access only the DOM element within its own component and how can I dynamically set the style for those elements?

app.comonent.html

```
<div class="columns mt-5  ml-5 mr-5">
    <div class="column is-12">
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="columns mt-5  ml-5 mr-5">
    <div class="column is-12">
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
</div>
```

title.component.html

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="title titleMain">Unity Projects</span>
        <div [style]="polygonDivStyle">
            <div class="titleDiv" id="unityTitle"  [style]="unityClipPath">
                <svg id="triangle" width="320" height="320">
                    <polygon points="155, 30  280, 280 30, 280" stroke-width="30" stroke="#FF6EFF" fill="none" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

title.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-title',
  templateUrl: './title.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./title.component.css']
})

export class TitleComponent implements OnInit {
  contactClipPath!: string;
  contactTitle!: HTMLDivElement | null;
  unityClipPath!: string;
  unityTitle!: HTMLDivElement | null;
  polygonDivStyle!: string;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.unityClipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%);`;
    this.unityTitle = document.getElementById('unityTitle') as HTMLDivElement| null
    this.RadialReveal(this.unityTitle, this.unityClipPath);
    this.polygonDivStyle = "";

  }
   @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
   onScroll(event:Event){
    this.RadialReveal(this.unityTitle, this.unityClipPath);
   }

  RadialReveal(clip:HTMLDivElement | null, clipPath:string) {
    let top = clip?.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let scrollPercent = 0;
    if(top && visualViewport)
      scrollPercent= ((top / visualViewport.height) * 300 -100);
    if (clip != null && scrollPercent > 1 && scrollPercent < 100) {
      this.polygonDivStyle = '';
      let scrollOpposite = 100 - scrollPercent;
      if(scrollOpposite >= 0 && scrollOpposite < 33)
      {
        clipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% `+[scrollPercent-67]+`% ,50% 33%, 0% 33%, 0% 66%, 100% 66%, 100% `+[scrollOpposite+66]+`%, 50% 66%, 0% 66%);`;
      }
      else if(scrollOpposite >= 33 && scrollOpposite < 66) 
      {
        clipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, `+[(scrollOpposite-34)*3]+`% 0% ,50% 33%, 0% 33%, 0% 100%,  `+[(scrollPercent-34)*3]+`% 100%, 50% 66%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);`;
      }
      else if(scrollOpposite >= 66 && scrollOpposite <= 100) 
      {
        clipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0% , 100% `+[33-scrollPercent]+`% ,50% 33%, 0% 33%, 0% `+[scrollPercent+66]+`%,50% 66%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);`;
      }
    }
    else if(scrollPercent > 100)
    {
      clipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%);`;
    }
    else if(scrollPercent < 1)
    {
      clipPath = `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0% , 100% 33% ,50% 33%, 0% 33%, 0% 66%,50% 66%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);`;
      this.polygonDivStyle = 'filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 200px #ff00ff) drop-shadow(-10px -10px 50px #ff00ff);'
      
      
    }
      this.unityClipPath = clipPath;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using getElementById within the title component try using @ViewChild

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-title',
  templateUrl: './title.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./title.component.css']
})

export class TitleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('unityTitle') unityTitle!: ElementRef;
    
    // your code goes here

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   // you can access the properties where you would normally do in elementRef
    this.unityTitle.nativeElement.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
    this.unityTitle.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';

  }
}
```

In your html. (Note the usage of html reference #unityTitle)

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="title titleMain">Unity Projects</span>
        <div [style]="polygonDivStyle">
            <div #unityTitle class="titleDiv" id="unityTitle"  [style]="unityClipPath">
                <svg id="triangle" width="320" height="320">
                    <polygon points="155, 30  280, 280 30, 280" stroke-width="30" stroke="#FF6EFF" fill="none" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've implemented the changes but now getting errors:

core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: clip.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at TitleComponent.RadialReveal (title.component.ts:32:20)
    at TitleComponent.ngAfterViewInit (title.component.ts:19:10)
I was not able to use ElementRef but HTMLDivElement worked (not sure if this is what was causing the problem) 
Also that is how I initially intended to set the style but there was no way to do it with "-webkit-clip-path" as far as I could see

Comment: can you try **this.unityTitle.nativeElement.style['-webkit-clip-path']= 'polygon(0% 0%)';**

Comment: Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jj7vhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you check the above stackblitz

Comment: I had to make a few small changes to the function to get this working but it now works exactly as intended. Thanks so much for your help Kelum!!